# Amazon S3 - CSS breaks arbitrarily on simple page

Tags: html, css, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, caching

I have the same page open in two different browsers on the same computer. On one, the styles are completely broken and all over the place. On the other, they are fine. I am dealing with a big project but, in this case, a very simple HTML file and a very simple assets folder with three stylesheets and 20ish images - these are all in the same folder.

**

- Notable info:

**

- I have invalidated every possible related cache. This seems to work *sometimes*.
- This issue seems to occur randomly and frequently - 50% of the time it looks fine, the rest it does not.
- I have uploaded fresh versions of CSS assets (with -v2 tags on the filenames) as well as changed the names of the HTML files and it has helped, but apparently only temporarily.
- In devtools, under sources, I can see the CSS files in both the working and broken browsers. They look different, but completely at random. Lines appear to be missing or added in one or the other.
- This was initially a Figma-exported page with a LOT of absolute positioning (I'm rebuilding it but it's not done).